# Issues showing tooltips in a dynamic d3 stack bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dynamic d3 stack bar chart. You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/twentyTwo/mL6agyvp/135/).

The chart is working fine without the tooltips. I want to add tooltips on each of the bars' stacks, which will show the corresponding values.

The code was,

```
 var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function (d) {
                    return d;
                });
```

And to add the tooltips, I have modified them to

```
var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
.data(function (d) {
    return d;
})
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });
```

The tooltip is not stable. It does not show in all the bars. I call the draw() method twice, tooltips then working in all the bars.

[image]

From the above, you can see, clicking the Quarter and Month button twice solves the problem.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the event handlers before you `append` the `rect`s.

The first time you go from Year to Quarter the tooltip only appears on the *first* column because the event has only been applied to the first `rect`s making up the column because there was only one column in the Year view.

Likewise, going from Quarter to Month, the tooltip only appears on the *first four* columns because that's how many columns were in the Quarter view.

When you click Quarter and Month for the 2nd (or more) occasion the `rect`s now exist from the first time the button was clicked and the event handlers can attach.

The consistent behaviour you're looking for is just a matter of taking this code

```
var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function (d) {
    return d;
  }) // ------------------------------------------------------------ remove from below ↓↓↓↓↓
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });
```

And moving it down to the section where you `append` `rect`s just after the `// Draw Legends ends` comment:

```
rect.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.x);
  })
  .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.y + d.y0);
  })
  .attr("height", function (d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
  }) 
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // -------------------------------- add below here ↓↓↓↓↓
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });
```